# Add a unique meta desciption

Tags: posts

How can I put the same meta description to pages and posts? To appear the same description when shared in social medias?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Can you clarify what you need and provide some image? Hard to follow.

Comment: Hi there Prosti, i have installed the plugin Cybersyn to improve my website with more content. But when the posts are sharing to facebook, have the description of youtube, with the links of the same. My question is, how i can retire the description and put the same description in all posts?

Comment: Sorry Prosti, i have only 6 mounths of wordpress :/

Comment: i will try to explain better

Comment: Not sure what you plan. What is the description? Is this the post content. [edit] your post and set the details from the comments. If you provide the quality question you will most probably receive the good answer.

Comment: i think it is the Meta description. When you sharing something of your wordpress website to facebook by SEO, you have the title, the description and the link to your website. Understand this part?

Comment: My question is, how i can have in all meta description the same description when posted to facebook or other social?

Comment: The same meta description for the open graph?

Comment: You should look into the SEO plugin by Yoast.

Answer (score 0):

For Open Graph descriptions, use a plugin like Complete Open Graph. It'll automatically use the content on your pages to generate the descriptions, but you can also set it globally and force it for all pages in the plugin's settings. Super straight forward.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/complete-open-graph/